# How to import csv file and save the content as model with correct number of columns using dJango

Tags: django

I am new to dJango. I have a lot of csv files which have different number of columns.

Importing a csv file and then saving it as database using model.py in dJango is a little bit simple. However, the problem is that my files have different number of columns. For example, `file A` has 3 columns, `file B` has 13 columns and `file C` has 22 columns. In this case, should I code each model for three different files? 
Is there a better way which can save any files without writing similar codes in `model.py`?

Comment: as per my understanding you want to import the CSV into table (no matter what fields are in CSV file) ? you want to create those fields automatically if not exists in the table ?

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed Yes. you got my thought. How can I achieve it? In my opinion, it is impossible.